# MySql Update where table_A.col_1 Between table_B.col_1 and table_B.col_2

Tags: mysql, sql-update

can you help me with an sql query?

I want to get a value from another table but cannot use an inner join because the "join" column is not exactly the same in these two tables. Instead I must check the place where "Table_A.clubZipCode BETWEEN  Table_B.zip_min AND Table_B.zip_max" holds.

This is my research efford so far:

```
UPDATE
    Table_A
SET
    Table_A.clubState = Table_B.state
FROM
    clubs_data AS Table_A
    JOIN zip_to_state AS Table_B
WHERE
    Table_A.clubZipCode BETWEEN Table_B.zip_min AND Table_B.zip_max
```

However it draws an syntax-error on line 5.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your query re-written with a valid syntax:

```
UPDATE clubs_data
SET clubState = (
                    SELECT state
                    FROM zip_to_state
                    WHERE clubs_data.clubZipCode >= zip_to_state.zip_min AND clubZipCode <= zip_to_state.zip_max
                    LIMIT 1
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you want to achieve, but generally the update syntax using JOIN would be something like this:

```
UPDATE clubs_data AS Table_A

JOIN zip_to_state AS Table_B
    ON Table_A.clubZipCode >= Table_B.zip_min 
    AND Table_A.clubZipCode <= Table_B.zip_max

SET Table_A.clubState = Table_B.state;
```

**EDIT**: [The solution just proposed by @Gab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42846252/1363190) using a subquery might be better suited for you in this case.

Comment: Thank you anyways. Good to know the right syntax for future queries.